# SpringSession WebSession with GemFire/Geode

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-session, spring-cloud-gateway

Is there any support or plan to support WebSession with GemFire/Geode?
Currently I can only find support for Redis and Map based Reactive Session management within the Spring Session project.

Comment: This seems like something that could be answered by reading documentation and/or the Spring Session issues/backlog

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no immediate plans to support WebSessions (i.e. Reactive Sessions) with Apache Geode, or by extension, Pivotal GemFire in [*Spring Session for Apache Geode/Pivotal GemFire*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode) (SSDG).

Much of this has to do with the fact that neither Apache Geode nor Pivotal GemFire is truly Reactive under-the-hood and therefore, does not provide a Reactive Java Client Driver.  Additionally, most of the data access operations between a *Spring Session* client and GemFire/Geode server/cluster, are `get` and `put` operations, which are not even Async, much less Reactive.

However, Reactive types wrapping some GemFire/Geode Async operations (e.g. CQ) are being explored, as can be tracked in [DATAGEODE-256](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGEODE-256).  Once the support in SDG is built, then SSDG can follow.  NOTE: SSDG builds on SDG as does some of the other *Spring Session* modules (e.g. *Spring Session Data Redis* and *Spring Session Data MongoDB*).  This effort should begin sometime mid-2020.

Feedback and/or contributions are always welcomed.  Use SSDG [Issues](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/issues) or [PRs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/pulls) for providing feedback.

Hope this helps clarify our current position on the matter.